# Error with while loop in pl sql

Tags: plsql, while-loop

I use while loop to calculate the integers from 1 to 10 in Pl Sql.

This is the code:

```
set serveroutput on;
declare
i number := 0;
sum number := 0;
begin
while i <= 10 loop
sum := sum + i ;
i := i + 1;
end loop;
dbms_output.put_line ( sum );
end;
/
```

what is the problem here?

This is the error message:

```
sum := sum + i ;
           *
ERROR at line 6: 
ORA-06550: line 6, column 12: 
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "+" when expecting one of the following: 
( 
ORA-06550: line 9, column 28: 
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol ")" when expecting one of the following: 
(
```

Comment: Please add what is wrong, what you are expecting. Any error message?

Comment: oh this is the error message
sum := sum + i ;
           *
ERROR at line 6: 
ORA-06550: line 6, column 12: 
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "+" when expecting one of the following: 
( 
ORA-06550: line 9, column 28: 
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol ")" when expecting one of the following: 
(

Answer (score 5):

Try not using the variable name `sum`.

i.e

```
set serveroutput on;
declare
i number := 0;
s number := 0;
begin
while i <= 10 loop
s := s + i ;
i := i + 1;
end loop;
dbms_output.put_line ( s );
end;
/
```

Seems to work